# Replace default Ionic webview with external website

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, webview

I'm trying to replace the default Ionic Cordova webview with the contents of an external website. I do not want this external website to open up the in app browser however. I simply want the app to display the website.

I've added the following to my config.xml file, but this just opens up a web browser and goes to the specified website.

```
<content src="https://somewebsite.com/" />
<allow-navigation href="*://*.somewebsite.com/" />
```

Comment: How about `location.href = "https://somewebsite.com/"` in JavaScript?

Comment: @AlexSteinberg Nope, that will open up the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Cordova InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) (directly or with the [Ionic wrapper](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser)) and use the target of `_self`. Since you've already whitelisted the URL, it should open in the webview.

e.g: `cordova.InAppBrowser.create('https://somewebsite.com/', '_self', 'usewkwebview=yes')`

Comment: Hmm, that snippet also just opens up a browser. What I need is the webpage to be inserted directly into the app. So no browser search bar and no other browser functionality.

Comment: Actually, I may have whitelisted the URL incorrectly. I'll try again